# Showing two lines on a triangle coincide

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, contest-math, analytic-geometry

Let $M$ be the midpoint of (the smaller) arc $BC$ in circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Suppose that the altitude drawn from $A$ intersects the circle at $N$. Draw two lines through circumcenter $O$ of $ABC$ paralell to $MB$ and $MC$, which intersect $AB$ and $AC$ at $K$ and $L$, respectively. Prove that $NK=NL$.

[image: Illustration]

Could someone check my proof for this problem? At the end I'm doing something wrong but I can't find where I messed up.

Let the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ be the unit circle.

Without loss of generality, let $m=1$ (lower case letter denotes complex number corresponding to the point). Then it is easy to see $b,c$ are reflections across the real axis, so $bc=1$. Now we may use the parallel condition to get the equation $\frac{l}{c-m}\in\mathbb{R}\implies \frac{l}{c-m}=\frac{\overline{l}}{\overline{c-m}}$, and solving for $\overline{l}$, we get $\overline{l}=-\frac{l}{c}$. Now using the fact that $l\in AC$, we have $\frac{a-l}{l-c}\in\mathbb{R}\implies\frac{a-l}{l-c}=\frac{\overline{a-l}}{\overline{l-c}}$, and solving for $\overline{l}$, we get $\overline{l}=\frac{a+c-l}{ac}$. Equating the two and solving for $l$, we get $l=\frac{a+c}{1-a}$. Similarly, $k=\frac{a+b}{1-a}$.

I am almost positive the above is correct, so I think I am making the error in the next part of the proof:

Since $AN\perp BC$, then $AN$ is parallel to the real axis, so $an=-1$. Let $P$ be the midpoint of $KL$. We want to prove $KL\perp PN$ (i.e. $N$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $KL$). To do this, we will prove $\frac{k-l}{p-n}\in i\mathbb{R}$, or $\frac{k-l}{p-n}+\frac{\overline{k-l}}{\overline{p-n}}=0$. Plugging in what we found earlier for $k,l,p$ (to get them in terms of $a,b,c$) and plugging in $n=-\frac{1}{a}$, we get that we want to prove:
$$\frac{\frac{b-c}{1-a}}{\frac{2a+b+c}{1-a}+\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{\frac{\frac{c-b}{bc}}{\frac{a-1}{a}}}{\frac{\frac{2}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{1-\frac{1}{a}}+a}=0$$

Which looks very intimidating, but we can easily simplify this to
$$\frac{1}{\frac{2a+b+c}{1-a}+\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{a}{\frac{\frac{2}{a}+b+c}{1-\frac{1}{a}}+a}=0$$ 
by dividing both sides by $\frac{b-c}{a-1}$, and taking advantage of the fact that $bc=1$ (also then $\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=b+c$).

But this simplifies to $a^2=1$, which is absurd since it would imply $M,N$ coincide, and therefore the triangle is isoceles. (I plugged this expression into my calculator, and that's what I got).

Where did I mess up? I checked all my steps and they all seem correct.

Comment: "Complex numbers" and "complex geometry" refer to something completely unrelated. This would be called "analytic geometry". I have changed the tags appropriately.

Comment: It seems to me there is something wrong: (1) what does mean "coincide" in your title? is it not the lenghts are equal?; (2) NK and NL are distinct and of different lenghts in a figure I carefully have drawn.

Comment: Yes, "coincide" does mean the lengths are equal (I originally just had my title as complex numbers geometry proof, but someone edited it to make it more specific). To address your second point, are you sure you drew the diagram correctly? I have a synthetic proof showing NK and NL are equal, I could post it if you like.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to prove $\frac{k-l}{b-c}\in i\mathbb{R}$. This cannot be true, in general.

Comment: Oops, yeah that was a typo. It was supposed to be $\frac{k-l}{p-n}\in i\mathbb{R}$ to show $KL\perp PN$ I fixed it now. However, there is still something wrong with my proof that leads to the end result of $a^2=1$

Comment: @Math: Thanks, I have drawn not correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your writup of the first half of the proof, so I'll concentrate on the second half.

One can use a computer algebra system to check the computation. I'm using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

```
sage: PR1.<a,b> = QQ[]  # Polynomial ring in two indeterminates
sage: def conj(x):      # Conjugation in its fraction field
...       return (x.numerator().subs(a=1/a, b=1/b) /
...               x.denominator().subs(a=1/a, b=1/b))
sage: c = 1/b
sage: l = (a+c)/(1-a)
sage: k = (a+b)/(1-a)
sage: p = (k+l)/2
sage: n = -1/a
sage: (k-l)/(p-n) + conj((k-l)/(p-n))
0
sage: res1 = ((b-c)/(1-a))/((2*a+b+c)/(1-a)+1/a) + (((c-b)/(b*c))/((a-1)/a))/((2/a+1/b+1/c)/(1-1/a)+a)
sage: res1
(a^3*b^3 - a^3*b - a*b^3 + a*b)/(-2*a^4*b^2 - 3*a^3*b^3 - a^2*b^4 + 3*a^3*b^2 + 2*a^2*b^3 - 3*a^3*b - 8*a^2*b^2 - 3*a*b^3 + 2*a^2*b + 3*a*b^2 - a^2 - 3*a*b - 2*b^2)
sage: factor(res1)
(-1) * b * (b - 1) * (b + 1) * a * (a - 1) * (a + 1) * (a^2*b + a*b^2 - a*b + a + 2*b)^-1 * (2*a^2*b + a*b^2 - a*b + a + b)^-1
sage: res2 = 1/((2*a+b+c)/(1-a)+1/a)+a/((2/a+b+c)/(1-1/a)+a)
sage: res2
(a^4*b^2 - a^3*b^2 - a^2*b^2 + a*b^2)/(2*a^4*b^2 + 3*a^3*b^3 + a^2*b^4 - 3*a^3*b^2 - 2*a^2*b^3 + 3*a^3*b + 8*a^2*b^2 + 3*a*b^3 - 2*a^2*b - 3*a*b^2 + a^2 + 3*a*b + 2*b^2)
sage: factor(res2)
a * (a + 1) * b^2 * (a - 1)^2 * (a^2*b + a*b^2 - a*b + a + 2*b)^-1 * (2*a^2*b + a*b^2 - a*b + a + b)^-1
sage: res1/res2 == (b - c)/(1 - a)
True
```

So yes, the term $\frac{k-l}{p-n}+\overline{\left(\frac{k-l}{p-n}\right)}$ is indeed equal to zero, as expected. But the first transformation you showed already has a different value. The subsequent simplification step is almost as you claimed in your post, except for an additional sign change. So that simplification in itself is valid, but the step before is wrong. So where exactly is the mistake?

```
sage: k - l == (b-c)/(1-a)
True
sage: p - n == (2*a+b+c)/(1-a)+1/a
False
sage: conj(k - l) == ((c-b)/(b*c))/((a-1)/a)
True
sage: conj(p - n) == (2/a+1/b+1/c)/(1-1/a)+a
False
sage: 2*p == (2*a+b+c)/(1-a)
True
```

Apparently you used $p=k+l$ but should have used $p=\frac{k+l}2$.

Comment: Oops, I meant to type $\frac{l}{c-m}\in\mathbb{R}\implies\frac{1}{c-m}=\frac{\overline{l}}{\overline{c-m}}$. Sorry for all the typos. But I still think there is something wrong in the second half of the proof.

Comment: @Math, well fix up your question then! I don't want to distinguish between typos and actual errors for you.

Comment: I fixed the errors in the first half of the proof. And yeah, $l=\frac{a+c}{1-a},k=\frac{a+b}{1-a}$ are definetly correct, so the mistake must be in the second half of the proof where I tried to prove $\frac{k-l}{p-n}\in i\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Math You still have $\bar l = -\frac lc$ in your post.

Comment: @Math Found your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A solution through elementary geometry is also possible.
[image]

We have that $AM$ is the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$, and by computing $\widehat{ALO}=\widehat{ACM}$ and $\widehat{AKO}=\widehat{ABM}$ it follows that $AKOL$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Let $\Gamma_R$ be the circumcircle of $AKO$, $J=AN\cap\Gamma_R$ and $M'$ the antipode of $M$ in the circumcircle of $ABC$. Since $MAM'$ is a right triangle, we have that $\widehat{OKA}$ and $\widehat{AM'O}$ are supplementary angles, hence $M'\in\Gamma_R$, too, and $OJ\parallel MN$. From $NJ=OM'$ and $OJ\perp NM'$ it follows that $NJ=NO$.

On the other hand, it is not difficult to prove that $KL\perp NM'$, too, since $\widehat{KAJ}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\widehat{B}$ and $\widehat{OAL}=\widehat{BAC}-\widehat{BAO}=\widehat{KAJ}$. It follows that $NK=NL$ as wanted.

Moreover, it happens that the intersection of $NM'$ and $AM$ lies on $\Gamma_R$, too.

Comment: *$\widehat{OKA}$ and $\widehat{AM'O}$ are supplementary angles* - Why?

Comment: @Lucian: $\widehat{OKA}=\widehat{MBA}=\widehat{B}+\frac{1}{2}\widehat{A}$ and $\widehat{AM'O}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\widehat{OAM}$. Both $\widehat{ABM}$ and $\widehat{AOM}=\pi-2\widehat{OAM}$ have the chord $AM$ in common.